# shell script to exclude entries of +ASM, AGENT, -MGMTDB from ORATAB file and just validate only DBSIDs

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

I have a SQL script which gets details about FRA (Flash recovery Area in ORACLE) which needs to be run only in DB's and not in any other oratab entries. So in the below case, i need it to execute only in dbname1 and dbname2 only and ignore rest of the entries when found.

example oratab file:

```
dbname1:/u01/app/oracle/11.2.0.4/db_1:Y
dbname2:/u01/app/oracle/12.2.0.1/db_2:Y
+ASM:/u01/app/grid:N
MGMTDB:/u01/app/grid:N
AGENT:/u01/app/agent_home:N
```

I wrote a function which i am currently using and not working properly as per my requirement. Any changes are greatly appreciated.

```
checkORATAB()
{
ORATAB=/etc/oratab
SID=`egrep -i ":Y|:N" $ORATAB | cut -d":" -f1 |grep -v "\#"|grep -v "\*"`
export $SID
if [[ `echo "$ORACLE_SID" | cut -b 1` != '+' ]] && [[ "$ORACLE_SID" != "AGENT" ]] && [[ "$ORACLE_SID" != "GRID" ]] && [[ "$ORACLE_SID" != "-MGMTDB" ]] && [[ "$ORACLE_SID" != "+ASM" ]]; then
for i in $SID; do
runscript;
fi
done
exit;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: while I have a general idea what a `oratab` file looks like, I'm not sure what you mean by `FRA`; also a bit confused by `validate only DBSIDs` vs `capture only DBSID`; I would suggest you update your question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You need to update/edit your original post with all of these additional details; other people coming to this question aren't going to bother reading through all of the comments and then try to put all the pieces together into a coherent question; have you read through that link (above) I provided in my first comment?  I suggest you also take a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you markp for guiding me to post it correctly..i am a beginner to stackoverflow and would not repeat this mistake again..!!

Comment: `awk -F: '$1 !~ /(+ASM|MGMTDB|AGENT)/ {print $1}'  /etc/oratab` will print just the 2 SIDs. Or using `sed -n '/^\(+ASM\|MGMTDB\|AGENT\)/b;s/:.*//p' /etc/oratab`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for `awk` or `sed` although a combination of `grep` and `cut` will also work.

```
checkORATAB() {
    ORATAB=/etc/oratab
    for sid in $(awk -F: '$1 !~ /(+ASM|MGMTDB|AGENT)/ {print $1}' $ORATAB)
    do
        export ORACLE_SID=$sid
        runscript
    done
}
```

Or using `sed`:

```
checkORATAB() {
    ORATAB=/etc/oratab
    for sid in $(sed -n '/^\(+ASM\|MGMTDB\|AGENT\)/b;s/:.*//p' $ORATAB)
    do
        export ORACLE_SID=$sid
        runscript
    done
}
```